# Center Text and BottomRight Text in Card

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout

How can I get the following effect on the Card widget?

[image]

This is my code:

```
Card(
        elevation: 4,
        color: const Color(AppColors.brighterBackground),
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: horizontalPadding,
                top: verticalPadding,
                right: horizontalPadding,
                bottom: verticalPadding),
            child: Column(children: [
              Text('CENTER HORIZONTALLY AND VERTICALLY',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: contentSize)),
              Text('BOTTOM-RIGHT',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: contentSize))
            ])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.

You can used **`Stack Widget`** [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) and **`Positioned Widget`** [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) . you used your padding on your need.

```
Card(
    elevation: 4,
    color: Colors.red,
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 10,
        top: 10,
        right: 10,
        bottom: 10,
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'CENTER HORIZONTALLY AND VERTICALLY',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            right: 1,
            child: Text(
              'BOTTOM-RIGHT',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: As an alternative to the Positioned widget, you can also use the **Align** widget and provide the **alignment: Alignment.bottomRight**  to it